# MachineKey for ViewState

Tags: asp.net, web-config, viewstate, session-state

If using a **dedicated** state server for session state in a web farm, is adding a machinekey for viewstate still necessary?

I know if there was **no** dedicated server for session state, that you would need to add the machinekey.

Answer (score 2):

ViewState is stored in-form (rather than in-session), hence in order for Machine B to decode ViewState from Machine A both machines need to share the same machine key. The Machine Key does not come into play for Session state, as there is no point in encrypting it.